# Delegate Action Never Gets Called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I'm having trouble using Protocols/Delegates when I was trying to reload the data from a UITableView in my rootViewController when my modal view is dismissed.

Here is some code from my modal view .h file:

```
@protocol LoginWebViewDelegate <NSObject>
     -(void) updateFromModalView;
@end

@interface myModalView : UIViewController{
    id<LoginWebViewDelegate> loginDelegate; 
    ..
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<LoginWebViewDelegate> loginDelegate;
..
-(IBAction)dismiss;
..
```

In my .m file I synthesize the loginDelegate & I implement the dismiss action & it's been activated when I press the button.

```
-(IBAction) dismiss
{
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed!");
    [loginDelegate updateFromModalView];
}
```

Next in the inteface of my rootViewController I added `<LoginWebViewDelegate>` & here is the action in my implementation:

```
-(void) updateFromModalView
{
    [modalView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Reloading Data");
    [dataController readPlist];
    [dataTable reloadData];
    [dataTable beginUpdates];
    [dataTable deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:YES];
    [dataTable insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:YES];
    [dataTable endUpdates];
}
```

The method updateFromModalView never gets called. What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing (or you haven't posted) the part where you assign a value to `loginDelegate`. You mention synthesising it but that only creates accessor methods, it doesn't set a value.

Somewhere in your code you need a statement like:

```
self.loginDelegate = _something_;
```

Or, whatever object creates this view controller would set itself or another object as the delegate after creating it but before presenting it:

```
modalController = [[ModalController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalController];
modalController.loginDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:modalController];
```